# Call C++ function from inside dynamically loaded dll

Tags: c++, c, dll, declspec

I'm writing a C++ programm that dynamically loads a dll at runtime and calls a function within that dll.
Thats working fine but now i want to call a function defined in my C++ programm from within the dll.

My main.cpp looks like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef void(*callC)(int);

int main()
{
    HINSTANCE dllHandle = LoadLibrary("D:\Libraries\lib.dll");

    callC func = (callC)GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "callC");

    func(42);

    FreeLibrary(dllHandle);
}

// I want to call this function from my dll
void callableFromDll(){
}
```

The part of the dll thats accessed is writtin in C and looks like as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void callC(int);

void callC(int i){
    print(i);

    // Call the C++ function
    //callableFromDll();
}
```

I've read about the `__declspec(dllimport)` and `__declspec(dllexport)` attributes but im really new to C++ and not sure if these are the right thing to use and if so, how to use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your C++ program:

```cpp
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void callableFromDll(int value) {
    printf("This function was called from the main process. Value: %d\n", value);
}
```

In your DLL:

```cpp
typedef void(*callableFromDll)(int);
callableFromDll func;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        func = (callableFromDll)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(NULL), "callableFromDll");
        func(69);
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:

        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

```cpp
GetModuleHandle(NULL)
```

Returns the parent's executable handle.

Console output from the exe when LoadLibrary has loaded the DLL:

```
This function was called from the main process. Value: 69

cppfunction.exe (process 16336) exited with code 0.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

`extern "C"` tells the compiler to not encode the function's name into a unique name. The compiler encodes names so that linkers can separate common function or variable names.

See [extern "C" and extern "C++" function declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/extern-cpp?view=vs-2019#extern-c-and-extern-c-function-declarations), [Exporting from a DLL Using __declspec(dllexport)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-declspec-dllexport?view=vs-2019)  and [Importing function calls using __declspec(dllimport)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/importing-function-calls-using-declspec-dllimport?view=vs-2019).

Comment: DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH is not in the console output, right?

Comment: So did I understand this right: the DllMain function is called when the dll is loaded by the main program? Does that mean i have to initialize all the external functions I want to use during this function call?

Comment: DllMain gets called when the dll is loaded. You don't have to initialize the functions inside DllMain, you can initialize them outside of DllMain like so: `callableFromDll func = (callableFromDll)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(NULL), "callableFromDll");`